# How to set the zIndex layer order for geoJson layers?

Tags: leaflet, z-index, mapbox, geojson

I would like to have certain layers to be always on top of others, no matter in which order they are added to the map. 
I am aware of `bringToFront()`, but it does not meet my requirements. I would like to set the zIndex dynamically based on properties.

Leaflet has the method `setZIndex()`, but this apparently does not work for geoJson layers:
https://jsfiddle.net/jw2srhwn/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

This is one of the reason for the implementation of user defined "panes" in Leaflet 1.0 (compared to versions 0.x).

1. Create [panes](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-createpane): `var myPane = map.createPane("myPaneName")`
2. If necessary, set the class / z-index of the pane element: `myPane.style.zIndex = 450` (refer to [z-index values of built-in panes](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-pane))
3. When creating your layers, specify their target [`pane`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layer-pane) option: `L.rectangle(corners, { pane: "myPaneName" })`
4. When building through the `L.geoJSON` factory, you can loop through your features with the `onEachFeature` option to clone your layers with specified target `pane`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/90/

Answer (score 9):

Cannot be done for vector geometries.

`zIndex` is a property of `HTMLElement`s, and vector geometries (lines and polygons) are rendered as SVG elements, or programatically as `<canvas>` draw calls. Those two methods have no concept of `zIndex`, so the only thing that works is pushing elements to the top (or bottom) of the SVG group or `<canvas>` draw sequence.

Also, remind that `L.GeoJSON` is just a specific type of `L.LayerGroup`, in your case containing instances of `L.Polygon`. Furthermore, if you read [Leaflet's documentation about the `setZIndex()` method on `L.LayerGroup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup-setzindex):

> Calls `setZIndex` on every layer contained in this group, passing the z-index.

So, do `L.Polygon`s have a `setZIndex()` method? No. So calling that in their containing group does nothing. It will have an effect on any `L.GridLayer`s contained in that group, though.

Coming back to your problem:

> I would like to have certain layers to be always on top of others, no matter in which order they are added to the map.

Looks like the thing you're looking for is map panes. Do read the [map panes tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes.html).

Answer (score 3):

**For peoples who are searching about Z-Index**

All path layers (so all except for markers) have no z-index because svg layers have a fix order. The first element is painted first. So the last element is painted on top. 
@IvanSanchez described good why zIndex not working.

You can control the order with `layer.bringToBack()` or `layer.bringToFront()`.

With that code you have more options to control the order of the layers.

```
L.Path.include({
    getZIndex: function() {
        var node = this._path;
        var index = 0;
        while ( (node = node.previousElementSibling) ) {
            index++;
        }
        return index;
    },
    setZIndex: function(idx) {
        var obj1 = this._path;
        var parent = obj1.parentNode;
        if(parent.childNodes.length < idx){
            idx = parent.childNodes.length-1;
        }
        var obj2 = parent.childNodes[idx];
        if(obj2 === undefined || obj2 === null){
            return;
        }
        var next2 = obj2.nextSibling;
        if (next2 === obj1) {
            parent.insertBefore(obj1, obj2);
        } else {
            parent.insertBefore(obj2, obj1);
            if (next2) {
                parent.insertBefore(obj1, next2);
            } else {
                parent.appendChild(obj1);
            }
        }
    },
    oneUp: function(){
        this.setZIndex(this.getZIndex()+1)
    },
    oneDown: function(){
        this.setZIndex(this.getZIndex()-1)
    }
});
```

Then you can call

- `polygon.oneUp()`
- `polygon.oneDown()`
- `polygon.setZIndex(2)`
- `polygon.getZIndex()`
- And now `layergroup.setZIndex(2)` are working